# Ant Command not Found

Tags: ant, windows-8.1

I am using Windows 8.1 and I have installed Apache Ant and put it in my `Program Files` directory, but when I try:

[image: Description]

I get:

[image: Description]

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your PATH variable to add the path of Ant. Instructions for how to edit your PATH are [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). Alternatively, you can type the full path of ant in the command.